# How to reset a variable value after running a certain command in bash

Tags: bash, variables, counter, ps1

i wanted to implement a cool feature for my PS1 prompt. I added \# string to show the command number of that command. My goal is that if a certain command is ran, the command number from \# to be set back to 1. I have some ideas but i don't know how to write it.
Is it possible to somehow export \# value as a variable, and when a command is run, the variable to be restored to the initial state. Actually this [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/434401/469653) says that its impossible.
If this doesn't work, can i create a counter that replaces \#, and then export it as a variable. That variable to be reset by a certain command.
https://www.baeldung.com/linux/bash-script-counter
Sorry i don't have enough knowladge in bash, hope i don't ask for the impossible. Thanks

Comment: Did you see [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/434409/make-a-bash-ps1-that-counts-streak-of-correct-commands) ?

Comment: @Zilog80 I have seen that post, but it does not answer my question. He wants his counter to reset every time he makes a mistake, in my case i want it to be reseted every time i run a certain command in shell.

Comment: In that case, using `if [ "\$(history| tail -n1)" -ne "<your reset command>" ]; ` instead of `if [ $? -eq 0 ]; ` will not do the trick ? Beware that you can't use `!-1` in a prompt context.

Comment: My bad, `if [ "\$(history| tail -n1| sed 's/^ *[0-9][0-9]*  //')" -ne "<your reset command>" ]; ` , to get rid of the history line number.

Answer (score 1):

I ran a quick test with a `trap`. This worked for me -

```
$: trap 'echo "$BASH_COMMAND"; [[ "$BASH_COMMAND" =~ ^:\ *reset ]] && trap -- debug' debug
set_titlebar
set_prompt
$: date
date
Fri Jun 25 08:29:26 CDT 2021
set_titlebar
set_prompt
$: : reset
: reset
$: date
Fri Jun 25 08:29:38 CDT 2021
$:
```

The `trap` checks `$BASH_COMMAND` for your key (I used `: reset`) and resets the `trap` when seen. Edit in whatever key and/or code you want.